# Elasticsearch Mapping Silent Conflict

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping

I'm new to working with Elasticsearch mappings. My data isn't behaving as expected with a mapping file that was in place before I started working with the data. The Elasticsearch instance is version 1.7.5

I've noticed there seems to be two levels where the same field is used in a `copy_to` in the mapping. Elasticsearch starts fine and data is pushed into it without any errors being thrown.

From the snippet below, I want to have my `record_type.FOO.date.earliest|latest` copied to the top level of my record for sorting purposes, but it looks to me like `ownership.date.earliest|latest` is conflicting. As a result, it looks like my `record_type` fields are not being copied to the other fields in my record. Is this correct?

```
    ..."ownership":
    {
        "properties":
        {
            "date":
            {
                "properties":
                {
                    "earliest":
                    {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "include_in_all": false,
                        "copy_to": "date.earliest"
                    },
                    "latest":
                    {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "include_in_all": false,
                        "copy_to": "date.latest"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "record_type":
    {
        "properties":
        {
            "archive":
            {
                "properties":
                {
                    "date":
                    {
                        "properties":
                        {
                            "earliest":
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "include_in_all": false,
                                "copy_to": "date.earliest"
                            },
                            "latest":
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "include_in_all": false,
                                "copy_to": "date.latest"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "public_record":
            {
                "properties":
                {
                    "date":
                    {
                        "properties":
                        {
                            "earliest":
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "include_in_all": false,
                                "copy_to": "date.earliest"
                            },
                            "latest":
                            {
                                "type": "integer",
                                "include_in_all": false,
                                "copy_to": "date.latest"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },...
```

### **In Short**

If I have two instances of `copy_to` in different levels of my mapping, will this create a silent conflict, or does my issue lie elsewhere?

Comment: I don't understand where you are copying those fields. To me it looks like you want to copy them to the same fields.

Comment: Assuming what I said above it's not true and you have something in your mapping that is either a typo or the mapping is incomplete, for `record_type` and `public_record` I would suggest being more specific: `"copy_to": "public_record.date.earliest"` etc. and `"copy_to": "archive.date.earliest"` etc. In 1.7 these ambiguous things could have been defined. 2.x is stricter.

Comment: Sorry it's unclear. This is just a snippet from the mapping. There is a higher level to the mapping where these are copying to, which works with the same format in other mapping files I have. For example, the top level is `library` and the `"copy_to":"date.latest"` is going to `library.date.latest`

Comment: Ok. I'd still suggest being specific when copying_to.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. With this example, however, and having the `copy_to` in the `ownership` structure, as well as the `record_type` structure, I assume this would create some kind of conflict if they're both copying to `library.date.earliest` and `library.date.latest`? Or is this not really possible to tell without plugging data into it?

Comment: You'd do `ownership.library.date.earliest` and `record_type.library.date.earliest`. Here, I'm assuming you have a `library` field in both `ownership` and `record_type`.

Comment: I don't, but I can. For better context, the ES type is `library`, and the mapping is `LibraryMapping.txt`, so it goes `library.record_type...` and `library.ownership...`.